# Shared Hosting SSH (rsync enabled) to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cpanel, rsync

I am looking to share/sync a folder on my shared web hosting to a bucket I have created in Google Cloud Storage. My host has enabled both SSH and rsync on my shared hosting. unfortunately, I cannot install rclone which should fit this job nicely. I have setup a Google Cloud f1micro VM and will be using this as the link as well as writing the syncs to GCS.

How can I connect the two?

Here is the standard command to rsync to a remote server via SSH. How could this be adapted to send to Google Cloud Storage? At the moment it returns an error of `Unexpected remote arg`

`rsync gcs1 ssh cpanelusername@hostingip:public_html/r1/ -p 26`

There is gsutil rsync but unsure whether this would work in this setup
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync

Does this need to run in opposite direction and link to my SSH from my Google VM which will run the rsync?

NOTE: Our SSH shared hosting port is 26

Comment: Use gsutil to sync your local folder to Cloud Storage running gsutil at your desktop. Then use gsutil to sync from Cloud Storage to your VM instance's folder (running gsutil in the instance).

Comment: Hi John, This is just shared hosting to Google Cloud VM. I have edited my question to make it a bit clearer. Just struggling to connect the two servers at the moment.

Comment: `rsync` does not support Google Cloud Storage. Use gsutil.